# How to avoid automatic closing of a window opened with window.showdailog()

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have the below code to show a window as a Dialog

```
 BrowserPopupWindow.Navigate(loginType, uri);
 BrowserPopupWindow.ShowDialog();
```

on the navigate method i am doing some  async webrequest , because of which the  execution path is returned and the Dialog closes , how do i keep the Dialog open till i get the response of my webrequest.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;
using Intel_ChromeBook_Grive.Utility;
using Intel_ChromeBook_Grive.Helpers;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Intel_ChromeBook_Grive.Views
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BrowserPopup.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BrowserPopup : Window
    {


        internal delegate void OutlookOAuthFecthed(string oauthURI);
        internal event OutlookOAuthFecthed OutlookOAuthFecthedEvent;
        DispatcherTimer TimeoutBrowser = new DispatcherTimer();
        bool iSAccessTokenFecthed = false;


        internal delegate void YahooGuidFetched(string guid);
        internal event YahooGuidFetched YahooGuidFetchedEvent;

        internal delegate void UserClosedBrowser(Constants.CurrentLoginType logintype);
        internal event UserClosedBrowser UserClosedBrowserEvent;

        private Constants.CurrentLoginType Logintype;
        Uri YahooUri;

        public BrowserPopup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TimeoutBrowser.Tick += TimeoutBrowser_Tick;
            TimeoutBrowser.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        }

        void TimeoutBrowser_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopupMessage.Messagepop(Strings.NetwokrErrorText);
            ClosePopUp();
        }


        internal void Navigate(Constants.CurrentLoginType logintype,Uri uri =  null) 
        {

            webbrowser.LoadCompleted +=webbrowser_LoadCompleted;
            webbrowser.Navigating += webbrowser_Navigating;
            webbrowser.Navigated += webbrowser_Navigated;
            if (logintype == Constants.CurrentLoginType.Google)
            {
                WizardLoader.isUserLoggedin = false;
                Logintype = logintype;
                webbrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout");
            }
            else if (logintype == Constants.CurrentLoginType.Outlook)
            {
                Logintype = logintype;
                webbrowser.Navigate(Constants.OutLook_signInUrl);
            }
            else if (logintype == Constants.CurrentLoginType.Yahoo)
            {
                Logintype = logintype;
                YahooUri = uri;
                webbrowser.Navigate("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?logout=1");
            }



        }

        void webbrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void webbrowser_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeoutBrowser.Start();
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }



        void webbrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {


            TimeoutBrowser.Stop();
            #region Google OAuth handle
            //if login is for google 
            if (Logintype == Constants.CurrentLoginType.Google)
            {

                //** Show the loading indicator till the actaul page is loaded
                if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains(Constants.AUTH_URI))
                {
                    webbrowser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains(@"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?") && !e.Uri.ToString().Contains(Constants.AUTH_URI))
                    {
                        webbrowser.Navigate(OAouthManager.BuildAuthenticationUri());

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mshtml.HTMLDocument theDoc = (sender as WebBrowser).Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
                        if (theDoc.title.ToLower().StartsWith("navigation cancelled"))
                        {
                            PopupMessage.Messagepop(Strings.NetwokrErrorText);
                            ClosePopUp();
                        }
                        else if (theDoc.title.ToLower().StartsWith("denied error"))
                        {
                            PopupMessage.Messagepop(Strings.UserDeniedText);
                          //  MessageBox.Show("User did not allow access");
                            ClosePopUp();
                        }
                        else if (theDoc.title.ToLower().StartsWith("success"))
                        {
                            // TheBrowserPop.IsOpen = false;
                            this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                            //  TheLogin_Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                            string OAouth = theDoc.getElementById("code").getAttribute("value");
                            OAouthManager m = new OAouthManager();
                            m.AccessTokenFetchedEvent += m_AccessTokenFetchedEvent;
                            m.GetAccessToken(OAouth);
                            while (Logintype == Constants.CurrentLoginType.Google && iSAccessTokenFecthed == false)
                            {

                            }

                        }
                    }

            }
            #endregion

            #region OutLook OAuth handle
            else  if (Logintype == Constants.CurrentLoginType.Outlook)
            {
                webbrowser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("code="))
                {

                    if (OutlookOAuthFecthedEvent != null)
                    {
                        OutlookOAuthFecthedEvent(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
                    }
                    ClosePopUp();
                }

                else if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("error=access_denied"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Strings.UserDeniedText);
                     ClosePopUp();
                }

                mshtml.HTMLDocument theDoc = (sender as WebBrowser).Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
                if (theDoc.title.ToLower().StartsWith("navigation cancelled"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Strings.NetwokrErrorText);
                    ClosePopUp();
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Yahoo OAuth handle
            if (Logintype ==  Constants.CurrentLoginType.Yahoo)
            {

                if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("http://www.test.com/?oauth_token"))
                {
                    webbrowser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                    if (YahooGuidFetchedEvent !=  null)
                    {
                        YahooGuidFetchedEvent(e.Uri.ToString());

                    }
                    webbrowser.LoadCompleted -= webbrowser_LoadCompleted;
                    ClosePopUp();

                } else  if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("logout"))
                {
                    webbrowser.Navigate(YahooUri);
                }
                else
                {
                    webbrowser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            #endregion

        }

        void m_AccessTokenFetchedEvent(GoogleAccessToken googleAccessToken)
        {
           // GoogleAccessToken TheFirstToken = OAouthManager.GetAccessToken(OAouth);
            if (googleAccessToken == null)
            {
                PopupMessage.Messagepop(Strings.NetwokrErrorText);
                ClosePopUp();
                return;

            }
            if (App.Current.Properties.Contains(Constants.G_AccessTokenKey))
            {
                App.Current.Properties[Constants.G_AccessTokenKey] = googleAccessToken.access_token;
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.Properties.Add(Constants.G_AccessTokenKey, googleAccessToken.access_token);
            }

            if (App.Current.Properties.Contains(Constants.G_RefreshTokenKey))
            {
                App.Current.Properties[Constants.G_RefreshTokenKey] = googleAccessToken.refresh_token;
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.Properties.Add(Constants.G_RefreshTokenKey, googleAccessToken.refresh_token);
            }

            WizardLoader.isUserLoggedin = true;
            ClosePopUp();
        }


        void ClosePopUp() 
        {
            TimeoutBrowser.Tick -= TimeoutBrowser_Tick;
            TimeoutBrowser = null;
            webbrowser.LoadCompleted -= webbrowser_LoadCompleted;
            this.Holderpanel.Children.Remove(webbrowser);
            webbrowser = null;
          //  this.Height = 0;
          //  this.Width = 0;
           // this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            Keyboard.ClearFocus();
            this.Close();
        }

        ~BrowserPopup() 
        {
            //webbrowser.Navigating -= 
        }

        private void TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            if (UserClosedBrowserEvent != null)
            {

                UserClosedBrowserEvent(Logintype);
            }

            ClosePopUp();
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Closing My window");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: updated the question with the code used in the popup,

Comment: Sanath, this code is somewhat messy. What do you need the timer for? Upon what event (i.e. when) do you want to close the dialog?

Comment: There are multiple condition on which i want to close the pop up, and timer i am using it to close the  popup if the webbrowser is not  loaded in about 10 seconds due to network error

Comment: So basically, one or more of those conditions don't work correctly, the dialog closes prematurely, and you're asking to help find a bug in your code, IIUC. If so, you may want to edit your question and provide some details about each condition.

Comment: if my understanding is right , the closing event of the window should fire .. but in my case it is not firing  and the code was working fine untill i chnaged the sync werequest to async

Comment: What do you mean? I don't see any [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) objects in your code. If you mean `Navigate`, it's an initially asynchronous method.

Answer (score 0):

Guess method ClosePopUp is invoked at somewhere unexpected. You should find out which conditional branch within LoadCompleted Event Handler your code went.

Comment: its already running in the main thread, i have subscibed to the closing event of the  dialog(), but the event is not firing either

Comment: Are you sure the dialog is really shown ever? Is it possible that you already get exception from the calling of method Navigate?

Comment: The Method ClosePopUp  is  never called in this case , had a break point there and its not called

Comment: Try to add try/catch block for the body of method Navigate.

Comment: Tried it ... No exception

Comment: Check to see if the dialog would appear when you disable the calling of Navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are closing your window on **webbrowser_LoadCompleted** event, it is obvious that your instance will close.

There are several **ClosePopup()** calls from your webbrowser_LoadCompleted event on conditions. If any of the conditions are accepted, your ClosePopup() (in which you have written **this.close**) method will be called which results in closing your form.

In short, closing your form on load event is not a good idea. You need to improve your applicaton logic for the same.

And as you said you have some async call, detailed logging of execution will help you in detail. I'd rather log events than debugging it. :-)

And you have used **TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown** event, which also closes the event, if you could disable it and try, i think it will resolve your issue.

Comment: have my logs in place, like is said the  ClosePopup() is never called , and the code works fine , if i make a synchronous web request  rather than a async request

Comment: TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown may cause the hassle. If you could bypass it for an instance, give it a try!